# How to outer join two data sets (based on multiple primary keys)?

Tags: javascript, join, outer-join

Say I have the following two datasets:

```
   var revenueTestData = [
{"YEAR": "2007", "MONTH": "1", "CUSTOMER": "Customer1", "REVENUE": "1938.49488391425"},
{"YEAR": "2007", "MONTH": "1", "CUSTOMER": "Customer2", "REVENUE": "75.9142774343491"},
{"YEAR": "2007", "MONTH": "2", "CUSTOMER": "Customer2", "REVENUE": "99.3456067931875"}];
```

and

```
    var costTestData = [
{"YEAR": "2009", "MONTH": "1", "CUSTOMER": "Customer4", "COST": "14425"},
{"YEAR": "2009", "MONTH": "1", "CUSTOMER": "Customer4", "COST": "7591"},
{"YEAR": "2009", "MONTH": "2", "CUSTOMER": "Customer5", "COST": "31875"}];
```

How can I (in sql terms) FULL OUTER JOIN the two datasets? And even more, can I do it based on multiple columns/primary keys? For example, in this case, join by YEAR and CUSTOMER and get all values of YEAR, CUSTOMER, REVENUE, even when years don't match up (in which case the missing column would be null).

I have come across the following beautifully written function with which I am able to do a LEFT JOIN and also decide which columns to include in my result set, but when years don't match up they fall out of the resultset (as is to be expected in an inner join):

```
function innerjoinData(primary, foreign, primaryKey, foreignKey, select) {
    var m = primary.length, n = foreign.length, index = [], c = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {     // loop through m items
        var row = primary[i];
        index[row[primaryKey]] = row; // create an index for primary table
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {     // loop through n items
        var y = foreign[j];
        var x = index[y[foreignKey]]; // get corresponding row from primary
        c.push(select(x, y));         // select only the columns you need
    }

    return c;
}
```

An example call looks like this:

```
var testChartData= innerjoinData(revenueTestData, costTestData, "YEAR", "YEAR", function (a, b) {
                return {
                    Year: b.YEAR,
                    Cost: a.COST,
                    Revenue: b.REVENUE
                };
            });
```

Perhaps someone can aid me in turning this into an outer join?

Comment: That call is throwing an error from the `select` callback. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'COST' of undefined". You can start by fixing that problem

Comment: Would the SQL look like `SELECT year, cost, revenue FROM revenueTestData FULL OUTER JOIN costTestData ON revenueTestData.year = costTestData.year`?

Comment: That would be joining using just year as primary key. Optimally there would also be an `AND revenueTestData.customer = costTestData.customer` in there, for multiple primary key joins.

Comment: That function only supports one key to join on

Comment: I know. I'd like to do an outer join, and if possible, but not necessarily, do it using multiple keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's code that will do a full join on a single key. You have to scan it from both sides, the code you showed was doing a left join, not an inner join. It shouldn't be too hard to support two keys, unlimited keys will take a little extra.

```js
function innerjoinData(primaryTable, foreignTable, primaryKey, foreignKey, selectColumns) {
    var primaryIndex = mapFromArray(primaryTable, primaryKey),
        foreignIndex = mapFromArray(foreignTable, foreignKey),
        resultSet = [];


    // Look for misses and matches from the left
    for (var i = 0; i < primaryTable.length; i++) {
        var primaryRow = primaryTable[i];
        var match = foreignIndex[primaryRow[primaryKey]];
        resultSet.push(selectColumns(primaryRow,  match || {}));
        
    }
    
    // Look for just misses from the right
    for (var i = 0; i < foreignTable.length; i++) {
        var foreignRow = foreignTable[i];
        if (!primaryIndex.hasOwnProperty( foreignRow[foreignKey] )) {
            resultSet.push(selectColumns({}, foreignRow))
        }        
    }
    

    return resultSet;

    function mapFromArray(list, keyByProp) {
        var map = {};
        for (var i = 0, item; item = list[i]; i++) {
            map[item[keyByProp]] = item;
        }
        return map;
    };
}

var revenueTestData = [{
    "YEAR": "2006",
        "MONTH": "1",
        "CUSTOMER": "Customer1",
        "REVENUE": "1938.49488391425"
}, {
    "YEAR": "2007",
        "MONTH": "1",
        "CUSTOMER": "Customer2",
        "REVENUE": "75.9142774343491"
}, {
    "YEAR": "2008",
        "MONTH": "2",
        "CUSTOMER": "Customer2",
        "REVENUE": "99.3456067931875"
}];


var costTestData = [{
    "YEAR": "2007",
        "MONTH": "1",
        "CUSTOMER": "Customer4",
        "COST": "14425"
}, {
    "YEAR": "2008",
        "MONTH": "1",
        "CUSTOMER": "Customer4",
        "COST": "7591"
}, {
    "YEAR": "2009",
        "MONTH": "2",
        "CUSTOMER": "Customer5",
        "COST": "31875"
}];


var testChartData = innerjoinData(costTestData, revenueTestData, "YEAR", "YEAR", function (primaryRow, foreignRow) {
    return {
        Year: foreignRow.YEAR || primaryRow.YEAR,
        Cost: primaryRow.COST,
        Revenue: foreignRow.REVENUE,
        Customer:foreignRow.CUSTOMER
    };
});

document.getElementById('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(testChartData, null, 4)
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed! Thank you! :)
Any chance on doing this using multiple primary keys?

Comment: @Cos We'll leave that as homework for you ;) You have to at least show that you've tried. If you try it and can't get it, then post a separate question showing what you've tried, actual results and expected results